# Regular Expression for 3 digit without 000

Tags: regex, google-forms

I want to write a regular expression on Google Form

First Character between 1 to 9
Second and Third any alphabets (Upper Case)
and next 3 characters should be number like 541 or 001 but not 000

This expression is also taking 000

```
[1-9][A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}
```

Comment: But this will make first digit from 1 to 9 and rest 2 digits between 0 to 9.

Comment: then change `[0-9]{3}` to `[0-9]{2}[1-9]` if you don't want the last digit to be  `0`.

Comment: But then user will not be able to enter 120

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use alternations:

```
[1-9][A-Z]{2}([1-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][1-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][1-9])
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJ1kE8/1)

Here,

- `[1-9]` - matches 1 digit from `1` to `9`
- `[A-Z]{2}` - two uppercase ASCII letters
- `([1-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][1-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][1-9])` - 3 alternatives:

  - `[1-9][0-9][0-9]` - 3-digit numbers starting with `1`
  - `[0-9][1-9][0-9]` - 3-digit numbers having `1` in the middle
  - `[0-9][0-9][1-9]` - 3-digit numbers ending with `1`

[image]

Also, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT6qD3/1).

Comment: I tried on google form, now it is also allowing `1AB`

Comment: I tried and [it works](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1kDlges4qwvKTdmP3ZbkbxCNP3k60P7KqW0GlkSVjijU/viewform?usp=send_form). Please check if you selected `Regular Expressions` and `Matches` options.

Answer (score 4):

Use a negative look-ahead to avoid the triple zero at the end:

```
[1-9][A-Z]{2}(?!000)[0-9]{3}
```

Comment: RE2 does not support lookaheads. Any number of upvotes won't make it work in Google Forms. *Can't save your changes. Copy any recent changes, then revert to an earlier revision*

Comment: @stribizhev I am getting that error. Can you explain what is that error ?

Comment: I explained. Lookarounds are not supported. You cannot use `(?!000)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the alternation operator
    [1-9][1-9][1-9]|0[1-9][1-9]|00[1-9]|0[1-9]0